# How to get flat record set back from stored procedure in Dapper.Net

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dapper

I've got a project running on SQL Server 2005. I have a stored procedure that accepts some input parameters, has 2 output parameters and also returns a result set from a select statement inside.

The data is not intending to be returned back as objects just a simple dto class 'Foo' which does not have a primary key.

I've tried to use Dapper.Net with the below code, but I get as far as the exception error returned

> When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id

Code:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@Code", code);
p.Add("@MessageControlId", getMessageControlId);
p.Add("@SuccessCode", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@ErrorDescription", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 255);

var result = this.db.Query(sql: "up_MessageProcessed_get", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Should I be able to do this with Dapper.Net? Should I calling something else to get a simple resultset back?

As requested, here is a shell of the procedure, 
it will set the returnvalues and also return 1 resultset.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_MessageProcessed_get]
@Code varchar(10),
@MessageControlID varchar(22),
@SuccessCode int OUTPUT,
@ErrorDescription varchar(255) OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN

Select 2 as MessageProcessID, 38349348 as StartNum, 3874900 as EndNum, GETDATE() as StartDate, GETDATE() as EndDate
SET @SuccessCode = 0
SET @ErrorDescription = 'Completed successfully'
END
```

Comment: Hmmm... That is odd - any chance we can see what up_MessageProcessed_get is doing, so we can understand the context?

Comment: discarding the logic, I've put an example of the outputs from the sproc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't so much an "answer" as a "needs more context", but: with the code as posted, it works fine (below). I suspect the issue here is specific to something inside the stored procedure - something peculiar it is doing:

```
public void TestIssue17648290()
{
    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    int code = 1, getMessageControlId = 2;
    p.Add("@Code", code);
    p.Add("@MessageControlId", getMessageControlId);
    p.Add("@SuccessCode", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    p.Add("@ErrorDescription", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 255);
    connection.Execute(@"CREATE PROCEDURE #up_MessageProcessed_get
@Code varchar(10),
@MessageControlID varchar(22),
@SuccessCode int OUTPUT,
@ErrorDescription varchar(255) OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN

Select 2 as MessageProcessID, 38349348 as StartNum, 3874900 as EndNum, GETDATE() as StartDate, GETDATE() as EndDate
SET @SuccessCode = 0
SET @ErrorDescription = 'Completed successfully'
END");
    var result = connection.Query(sql: "#up_MessageProcessed_get", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    var row = result.Single();
    ((int)row.MessageProcessID).IsEqualTo(2);
    ((int)row.StartNum).IsEqualTo(38349348);
    ((int)row.EndNum).IsEqualTo(3874900);
    DateTime startDate = row.StartDate, endDate = row.EndDate;
    p.Get<int>("SuccessCode").IsEqualTo(0);
    p.Get<string>("ErrorDescription").IsEqualTo("Completed successfully");
}
```

which outputs:

```
Running TestIssue17648290 - OK!
```

(which is to say: that works fine)

Comment: @Jafin if there's a bug, I'm happy to look into it - but *ideally* I need to be able to repro first